# Itemwiter not able write output file in smb location when application deployed insta linux machine spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, smb

FlatfileItemWritter not able to write smb file location when I deploy the application in linux machine when in windows machine am able ton write. Please anyone suggest solution , am trying from while.

Smb file not able to write output file smb  location as resource.

Comment: New flatfileItemwriterBuilder <response obj>().name("writer").resource(smbfile location).build(); this snipshot works in windows machine when I deploy to linux server it is not writting where as file crearing

Comment: Is the process running your batch job has the rights to write in that location? Can you try to write in that location without spring batch first?

Comment: Thanks for the replay, am able to write  with byte data but not when am passing the resource file directly not able to write